# Why am I losing the reference to "self" when I call a function with "module_object[function_name]();"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, this, self

I have a file `tools.js` where I have multiple functions:

```
const another_module = require('another_module');

module.exports = {

    js_call: function(args={}) {
        /*  This function is executed when a JavaScript function should be called
            Call structure:
                args = {
                    'object': 'object.name',
                    'function': 'method_name',
                    'params': ['arg1', 'arg2']
                }
        */
        var self = this;
        var o = null;
        if ('object' in args) {
            if (args.object == 'tools') {
                o = self;
            }
            if (args.object == 'another_module') {
                o = another_module;
            }
        }
        if ('function' in args) {
            if ('params' in args) {
                o[args['function']].apply(null, args['params']);
            } else {
                o[args['function']]();
            }
        }
    },

    loaded_function: function (params={}){
        var self = this;
        self.test_function();            // this does not work here >> self.test_function is not a function 
    },

    test_function: function (){
        console.log('TEST');
    }
}
```

So if I do this in another module:

```
const tools = require('tools');

params = {
    'object': 'tools',
    'function': 'loaded_function',
}

tools.js_call(params);
```

I get the error

```
self.test_function is not a function
```

I am wondering if I am losing the `self` context when I call the function with `o[args['function']]();` or with `o[args['function']].apply(null, args['params']);`.

How can I solve or workaround this?

**Note**: I am using Node.js 8.9.3

Comment: If this is your exact code, I just want to make sure it's not a syntax error? You don't have a comma after the definition of `loaded_function`

Comment: Nope, it is not a syntax error, the error is `self.test_function is not a function`. I am going to add the comma to the question, thanks @sbrass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `apply` with `self` as the first parameter, the functions will run in the same context with `self`.

```
o[args['function']].apply(self, args['params']);
```

Comment: That´s working thanks. Actually I think this is more appropriate for my code: `o[args['function']].apply(o, args['params']);` to make work the call with other modules. I have read more information about the parameter [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Syntax)